# How can I trigger an event in shell script when an USB device is removed?

Tags: linux, shell-script, usb

I need to do some actions when a specific USB device is removed/added. I need a fast response on the order of milli-seconds.

How can I do this in a shell script?

Comment: I don't know exactly how you could do this, but look into udev rules. that should help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Linux distribution with udev support and you have root/administrator access to it then you can use udev rules to trigger on specific operations.

If the following example is added to a */etc/udev/rules.d/example.rules* then it will run the specified script when a block device is added with the specified parameters.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="HitachiGST", ATTRS{serial}=="31001206110000000000", RUN+="/a/script/to/run.sh"
```

That particular rule executes when my USB harddrive is inserted and attaches to the block system. It is quite easy to tweak the rules to match a specific lowlevel USB event.

I found the [Debian UDEV wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/udev) and [Writing Udev Rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) site to be very helpful in getting the right rules for my situation.

Answer (score 3):

As an initial answer you could listen for changes in the file `/proc/bus/input/devices` and check for `USB entries`. With this you can avoid polling the device. Or you can perform a loop polling when the device is inserted.

Probably shell script won't be as fast as you want. Would be better to use another script language `Python` or `C/C++`.

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/examples-code.html
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/